# Laravel Passport: auth:api behaving like auth:web

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, access-token, laravel-passport

I am trying to implement `passport` in my application to authenticate the `api` calls. I have done the configuration as mentioned in the official documentation.
I have this in my auth guard:

```
'api' => [
            'driver' => 'passport',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
```

And, this in my `AuthServiceProvider's` `boot()` method:

```
Passport::routes();
```

And this is the `route` I am trying to access:

```
    Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});

Route::group(['namespace' => 'Api', 'middleware' => 'auth:api'], function () {
    // Login Controller
   Route::get('/getclc', 'PreController@getClc');
});
```

I am sending the `header` in the request like this:

```
Authorization:Bearer $accessToken
```

My question is: 1. When a protected route is requested, it sends me to login page, but I want it to return the 401. How can I do that?

My `laravel` version is 5.4.33.

Comment: Could you show us all the routes?

Comment: @AntonisTsimourtos I have updated my question with all the routes. Please have a look.

Comment: Well the error clearly means that "login" route is not defined. You could try running `php artisan make:auth` [to scaffold the authentication pages needed](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication). Then you could try using `php artisan clear:cache`

Comment: I did what you said, and now it sends it to login page instead of returning the error.

Comment: So "the problem is solved". Now probably you will have to think what you want to do? Do you want to return a 401 if user is not authenticated or redirect him to login page? You could update your question too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When authentication fails, Laravel throws an `AuthenticationException` exception. This exception is handled by your Laravel exception handler, and eventually calls the `unauthenticated()` method in your `app/Exceptions/Handler.php` file.

You can see from that method that if your request expects a json response, you'll get a 401 Unauthenticated response. However, if you're not expecting a json response, it just redirects to the route named "login". This will obviously fail if you don't have a route named "login".

Your request "expectsJson" when you send either the "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest" header, or the "Accept: application/json" header. Otherwise, it is considered a normal web request.

If you'd like to change how your application handles unauthenticated users, the `unauthenticated()` method is the one to change.

Answer (score 2):

Add this code on Headers on postman.

```
key           Value
Accept        application/json
```

Thanks